# rbinding a list of data frame R with NULL

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frame structure like this:

Lets call this list listA:

```
$ :'data.frame':      1 obs. of 3 variables:
 ..$ a             :chr a1
 ..$ b             :chr b1
 ..$ c             :chr c1

$ : NULL

$ :'data.frame':      1 obs. of 3 variables:
 ..$ a             :chr a3
 ..$ b             :chr b3
 ..$ c             :chr c3
```

How do I preserves the order of the data, keeping the record NULL with either NA and form a data frame like this?

```
     a    b    c
1:  a1    b1   c1
2:  NA    NA   NA
3:  a3    b3   c3
```

I have tried to use:

```
listA <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, listA))
```

but the end result will skip the second row, becoming like this:

```
     a    b    c
1:  a1    b1   c1
2:  a3    b3   c3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a condition to get `NA` if it is NULL and then do the `rbindlist`

```
rbindlist(lapply(listA, function(x) if(is.null(x)) data.frame(a = NA, b = NA, c= NA) else x))
#    a  b  c
#1: a1 b1 c1
#2: NA NA NA
#3: a3 b3 c3
```

---

Another option may be to assign the `NULL` based on the `lengths` (which return 0 for NULL elements) to assign 'data.frame' with NA elements and then do the `rbindlist`

```
listA[!lengths(listA)] <-  list(data.frame(a = NA, b = NA, c = NA))
rbindlist(listA)
```

Comment: Ah! so before we rbind the list,  we can first tell it to replace null to NA for each column! Smart!

Comment: @Gabriel  Otherwise, the `NULL` element is skipped or removed when you do the rbind

Comment: Thanks this works, however it is a bit slow. I have like 1000000 records. I tried mclapply but window don't support forking. Any other lapply function I can use?

Comment: Hi @akrun, is there any base R alternative to the `rbindlist`?

Comment: @cliu You can use `do.call(rbind, yourlist)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun but it will drop the `NA`. Is there any base R way to still keep `NA`s in the ouput?

Comment: @cliu I don't see that problem with `lst1 <- list(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 2), data.frame(a = NA, b = NA, c = NA));
do.call(rbind, lst1)`

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I will give it another try.

Comment: @cliu If you have `NULL` elements, it would be removed though.  When you specificially say that it is `NA`, that is the reason I said it won't be removed