# Reading from an excel file having empty sheets as list and converting to a data frame in R. Error in bind_rows

Tags: r, excel, list, dataframe

I have an excel file with multiple sheets(>70)and I am reading from these sheet as a list and converting these to a data frame using the following function.

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
    
    sheets <- getSheetNames(filename)
    x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) read.xlsx(filename, sheet = X))
    names(x) <- sheets
    
    ###Convert to a dataframe with list name as column
    DF <- bind_rows(x, .id = "SampleName")
    DF
    }
```

But bind_rows is creating issue when an excel sheet has 0 rows and only column headers.
Error: Can't combine `List1$Name`  and `List2$Name` .

I tried this solution [rbinding a list of data frame R with NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793099/rbinding-a-list-of-data-frame-r-with-null), but is not working in my case. I need a new column with the sheetname, for separating each list.

An example data is posted below:

```
      dput(x)
      list(HR = structure(list(Name = c("John", "Jason", "Eliza", "Linda"
          ), Age = c(27, 42, 30, 28), Title = c("HR Genaralist", "HR Manager", 
      "Project Manager", "Safety Manager")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame"), 
      IT = structure(list(Name = c("Nivin", "Matt", "Jose", "Jacky"
      ), Age = c(35, 28, 40, 50), Title = c("Security Architect", 
      "Manager", "Engineer", "Project Manager")), row.names = c(NA, 
      4L), class = "data.frame"), Scientific = structure(list(Name = c("Betty", 
      "Dan", "Rob", "Bob"), Age = c(35, 40, 43, 45), Title = c("Data Analyst", 
      "Data Analyst", "Data Scientist", "Data Scientist")), row.names = c(NA, 
      4L), class = "data.frame"), Volunteer = structure(list(Name = logical(0), 
      Age = logical(0), Title = logical(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"))
```

Thank you.

Comment: I tried  the below solution. Is there any other better way.
        
             z <- lapply(x, function(y) if(nrow(y) == 0) data.frame(Name = NA , Age = NA, Title = NA) else y)
        
        DF <- bind_rows(z, .id = "SampleName")

Comment: `bind_rows()` is from what package?

Comment: bind_rows from dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rbind()` from base R:

```
do.call(rbind, x)

              Name Age              Title
HR.1          John  27      HR Genaralist
HR.2         Jason  42         HR Manager
HR.3         Eliza  30    Project Manager
HR.4         Linda  28     Safety Manager
IT.1         Nivin  35 Security Architect
IT.2          Matt  28            Manager
IT.3          Jose  40           Engineer
IT.4         Jacky  50    Project Manager
Scientific.1 Betty  35       Data Analyst
Scientific.2   Dan  40       Data Analyst
Scientific.3   Rob  43     Data Scientist
Scientific.4   Bob  45     Data Scientist
```

Using `data.table`:

```
rbindlist(x, idcol = "sheet")

         sheet  Name Age              Title
 1:         HR  John  27      HR Genaralist
 2:         HR Jason  42         HR Manager
 3:         HR Eliza  30    Project Manager
 4:         HR Linda  28     Safety Manager
 5:         IT Nivin  35 Security Architect
 6:         IT  Matt  28            Manager
 7:         IT  Jose  40           Engineer
 8:         IT Jacky  50    Project Manager
 9: Scientific Betty  35       Data Analyst
10: Scientific   Dan  40       Data Analyst
11: Scientific   Rob  43     Data Scientist
12: Scientific   Bob  45     Data Scientist
```

To keep empty data.frames as one row of `NA`, you can preprocess:

```
x <- lapply(x, function(x) if (nrow(x) == 0L) {x[1, ]} else x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I would like to keep the row for Volunteers as                  
 13  Volunteer  <NA>  NA               <NA>

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` after `discard`ing or `keep`ing only the `list` elements with more than one row

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
keep(x, ~ nrow(.x) >0) %>%
     bind_rows(.id = 'sheet')
#       sheet  Name Age              Title
#1          HR  John  27      HR Genaralist
#2          HR Jason  42         HR Manager
#3          HR Eliza  30    Project Manager
#4          HR Linda  28     Safety Manager
#5          IT Nivin  35 Security Architect
#6          IT  Matt  28            Manager
#7          IT  Jose  40           Engineer
#8          IT Jacky  50    Project Manager
#9  Scientific Betty  35       Data Analyst
#10 Scientific   Dan  40       Data Analyst
#11 Scientific   Rob  43     Data Scientist
#12 Scientific   Bob  45     Data Scientist
```

---

If we wanted to keep the data.frame where there are 0 rows to NA, then

```
map_dfr(x, ~ if(nrow(.x) == 0).x[1,] else .x, .id = 'sheet') %>% 
          as_tibble
# A tibble: 13 x 4
#   sheet      Name    Age Title             
#   <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <chr>             
# 1 HR         John     27 HR Genaralist     
# 2 HR         Jason    42 HR Manager        
# 3 HR         Eliza    30 Project Manager   
# 4 HR         Linda    28 Safety Manager    
# 5 IT         Nivin    35 Security Architect
# 6 IT         Matt     28 Manager           
# 7 IT         Jose     40 Engineer          
# 8 IT         Jacky    50 Project Manager   
# 9 Scientific Betty    35 Data Analyst      
#10 Scientific Dan      40 Data Analyst      
#11 Scientific Rob      43 Data Scientist    
#12 Scientific Bob      45 Data Scientist    
#13 Volunteer  <NA>     NA <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. But I would like to keep the empty data frame with NA values.